# probability of $P(X=1), P(X=2)$, where $X$ is number of defects

Tags: probability

Let $_$, $i = 1, 2, 3$ be the event that the system has a defect of type $i$

$P(A_1) = 0.17$
$P(A_2) = 0.07$
$P(A_3) = 0.13$

$P(A_1 \cup A_2) = 0.18$
$P(A_2 \cup A_3) = 0.18$
$P(A_1 \cup A_3) = 0.19$

Finally, $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = 0.01$

Find $P(X=1)$, where $X$ is number of defects.

For $P(X = 0)$, we can get $0.81$ by finding $P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)$, which is $0.19$. $0.19$ also means chances of exactly one defect am I correct in understanding that?

Second question:- $P(X=2)$ which then should be :- $P(A1 \cap A2) + P(A_2 \cap A_3) + P(A_1 \cap A_3) - 2P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A3)$

Both $P(X=1)$ and $P(X=2)$ are resulting in a wrong answer.

Comment: How is $A_i$ defined?

Comment:  = 1, 2, 3 be the event that the system has a defect of type i @N.F.Taussig

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: You should write $A_i$, where $i \in \{1, 2, 3\}$, is the event that the system has a defect of type $i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that $\Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3) = 0.19$.  You can obtain this result by using the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  You have also calculated $\Pr(X = 0)$ correctly.

You cannot conclude that $\Pr(X = 1) = \Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)$ since the union includes outcomes in which there are two or more defects.

$\Pr(X = 1)$ means that there is exactly one defect. If we simply add $\Pr(A_1)$, $\Pr(A_2)$, and $\Pr(A_3)$, we will have counted each event in which two defects occur twice and each event in which all three defects occur three times, once for each way of designating one of the defects as the defect that occurs.  We do not want to count outcomes with more than one defect at all.  Therefore, we must subtract each outcome in which two defects occur twice.  However, if we do so, we will have subtracted each outcome in which all three defects occur six times, twice for each of the $\binom{3}{2}$ ways we could have designated two of the three defects as the pair of defects that occurs.  Since we do not want to count outcomes with three defects at all, we must add three times the probability that all three defects occur to our total.
\begin{align*}
\Pr(X = 1) & = \Pr(A_1) + \Pr(A_2) + \Pr(A_3)\\
           & \qquad - 2[\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2) + \Pr(A_1 \cap A_3) + \Pr(A_2 \cap A_3)]\\
           & \qquad\qquad + 3\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)
\end{align*}

$\Pr(X = 2)$ means that exactly two of the three events occur. If we simply add $\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2)$, $\Pr(A_1 \cap A_3)$, and $\Pr(A_2 \cap A_3)$, we will count each outcome with three defects three times, once for each of the $\binom{3}{2}$ pairs of defects it contains.  We do not wish to count outcomes with three defects at all, so we must subtract them three times.  Hence,
$$\Pr(X = 2) = \Pr(A_1 \cap A_2) + \Pr(A_1 \cap A_3) + \Pr(A_2 \cap A_3) - 3\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)$$

Comment: Since the defects are mutually inclusive, it's better to write $\textrm{Pr}(A_1\cap A_2^C\cap A_3^C)$ instead of $\textrm{Pr}(A_1)\textrm{Pr}(A_2^C)\textrm{Pr}(A_3^C)$. I could be wrong, what do you think? This is why I deleted the comment. :(

Comment: @Nothingspecial  You are correct since we do not know that the events are independent.  I decided to rewrite my answer using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.  If you come up with a better approach, I would like to see your answer.

Comment: +1 (also) : Nice explanation.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig There's another way to look at it: $P(A_1\cap A_2^C \cap A_3^C) = P(A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3) - P(A_2\cup A_3)$. Doing the same for $P(A_2\cap A_1^C \cap A_3^C)$ and $P(A_3\cap A_1^C \cap A_2^C)$, you get $P(X=1) = 3P(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3) - P(A_1\cup A_2)-P(A_2\cup A_3)-P(A_3\cup A_1)$

Comment: @Nothingspecial  With the given information, that is a useful approach.